Azure Pipeline android-manifest-version@1 Task Unable to find matched key
I am using Azure pipelines to build and distribute Android app which is coded in React Native. In order to Auto increment the version number for android builds, I am trying to use the android-manifest-version@1 task.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-473885.motz-mobile-buildtasks
Here is the task I end up using -
- task: android-manifest-version@1
  inputs:
    sourcePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    versionCodeOption: 'buildid'
    versionCode: '$(Build.BuildId)'
    versionCodeOffset: '1'
    versionName: 
    printFile: true

But when I run it, it gives the following error
Unable to find matched key
Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help or guidelines is appreciated.

Could this error potentially be because you have not specified the versionName input?

The guideline says if I dont want to change version Name then leave that field blank.

Based on your description, I can reproduce the same issue. To fix the error, we need to make sure there are keys of android:versionCode and android:versionName="1.0" to be replaced by the `` task in the AndroidManifest.xml
Here is a sample for your reference.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ms.appcenter.sampleapp.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="ms.appcenter.sampleapp.android.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>



Yes I ended up adding this explicitely in Manifest to get this to work. for some reason the build function wasnt adding it based on the gradle values. But even after that, when i build the app, it only takes the default version code. Doesnt upgrade it.

I figured it out. I had to remove it from build.gradle for this to work. Or else it was getting overriden.

@KapilG, Many thanks for the update. Would you please briefly introduce your solution in the answer section below. Your sharing is much appreciated.
